# Leaflet in ioslides_presentation puts unnecessary white space in box to toggle layers. Way to reduce size of box? More help needed

Tags: r, r-leaflet, ioslides

My problem is exactly the same as the problem found here: [Leaflet in ioslides_presentation puts unnecessary white space in box to toggle layers. Way to reduce size of box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762088/leaflet-in-ioslides-presentation-puts-unnecessary-white-space-in-box-to-toggle-l)

But I do not know where or how to add the css code to my r document.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to include css in an R markdown file is by putting it between the html `<style>` and `</style>` tags, like this:

Make sure you put the style tags *below* the header bit (under the second `---`)

If you edit your question to include your data and code, we could probably give a more specific answer.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Russ"
date: '2023-03-18'
output: html_document
---

<style>

p {
  color: red;
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;



</style>


## R Markdown
```

This is what it looks like after rendering:

[image: R markdown with CSS example]

Comment: Many thanks Russ, your example explained enough that I put the css code in the right place this time - after the title of the slide and before the code for the leaflet map within that slide.